# Base Controller laravel 4 setuplayout method convert to laravel 5 view share is not working

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, radix

```
//base controller layout method please correct it.
protected function setupLayout()
    {
                $user = \Auth::user();
                if (!is_null($user)) {
                    $countries = [];
                    // $message = Member::find("id_member_status",`enter code here` "=", 9)->get();

                    // if ($message) {

                    //     return \View::make('member::block.message_member');

                    // } else{

                    //     return 'Teste';

                    // }


                    $notification = Notification::where('id_member','=',\Auth::id())
                    ->count();

                    if($notification > 0):
                        $notification_msg = Notification::with('notificationTitle')
                    ->where('id_member','=',\Auth::id())
                    ->orderBy('read','ASC')
                    ->orderBy('id_notification','DESC')
                    ->take(30)
                    ->get();

                    $notification_unread = Notification::where('id_member','=',\Auth::id())
                    ->where('read','=','0')
                    ->count();

                    if($notification_unread > 0):
                        $notification = 1;
                    else:
                        $notification = 0;
                    endif;

                    else:
                        $notification_msg = null;
                    endif;

                    $balance = $user->balance();
                    $years   = $user->proceedings()
                    ->where("id_status", Proceeding::STATUS_CONCLUDED)
                    ->where("id_source_description", Proceeding::SOURCE_WITHDRAW)
                    ->groupBy(\DB::raw("YEAR(updated_at)"))
                    ->get([\DB::raw("YEAR(updated_at) as year")])
                    ->lists("year");

                    //selects all convertitos points for qualifying
                    $currentPointsConverted = \Auth::user()
                    ->points()
                    ->where("id_source_description", PointSourceDescription::POINT_CONVERTED_SMALLER)
                    ->whereIn("id_type", array(Points::POINT_TYPE_CONVERTED_POINTS, Points::POINT_TYPE_CONVERTED_ROYALTY))
                    ->sum("point") * (-1);

                    if (is_null(\Auth::user()->nextClassification())) {

                        $percent = 100;

                    } else {

                        //initial points
                        $initialPoint = \Auth::user()->Classification()->points;

                        //final points
                        $finalPoint = \Auth::user()->nextClassification()->points;

                        //current points
                        $currentPointsConverted = $currentPointsConverted;

                        //endpoints least starting points
                        $finalFewerInitialPoint = $finalPoint - $initialPoint;

                        //Current points lower thresholds
                        $currentFewerInitialPoint = $currentPointsConverted - $initialPoint;

                        //calculating the percentage
                        $percent = round(($currentFewerInitialPoint * 100) / $finalFewerInitialPoint, 2);
                        $percent = $percent > 100 ? 100 : $percent;

                    }

                    $findSettings = Settings::where("setting_name", "=", "module_customer")->first();

                    $moduleCustomer = $findSettings->setting_value;

                    $weekBalance = array(
                        (int)$user->getBalanceUntilDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days'))),
                        (int)$user->getBalanceUntilDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-4 days'))),
                        (int)$user->getBalanceUntilDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days'))),
                        (int)$user->getBalanceUntilDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days'))),
                        (int)$user->getBalanceUntilDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days'))),
                        (int)$user->balance()
                        );
                    $countries = $country = array_map(function ($k) {
                      return $k[0];
                  }, \Config::get('app.available_languages'));



                    $ProceedingAwaitingReceipt = Proceeding::whereIn('net_proceeding.id_status', array(
                        Status::STATUS_AWAITING_RECEIPT
                        )
                    )->where('net_proceeding.id_requestor', '=', \Auth::id())
                    ->where('id_source_description', '=', Description::SOURCE_WITHDRAWN)
                    ->join('net_withdraw', 'net_withdraw.id_proceeding', '=', 'net_proceeding.id_proceeding')
                    ->count();

                    \View::share(
                        array(
                            "pending_p"        => (Member::STATUS_WAITING_PAYMENT == $user->id_member_status),
                            "pending_document" => !$user->haveDocumentBeenSended(),
                            "years"            => $years,
                            "user"             => $user,
                            "percent"          => $percent,
                            "weekBalance"      => $weekBalance,
                            "moduleCustomer"   => $moduleCustomer,
                            "notification"     => $notification,
                            "notification_msg" => $notification_msg,
                            "countries"        => $countries,
                            "hasUnreadTicket"  => Ticket::hasUnreadAnswer('user'),
                            "currentPointsConverted" => $currentPointsConverted,
                            "ProceedingAwaitingReceipt" => $ProceedingAwaitingReceipt,
                            )
                        );
                }

                if (!is_null($this->layout)) {
                    $this->layout = \View::make($this->layout);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You want us to "correct" that code without any kind of further explanation?